# Nice commands in a .sh script for cron jobs

Tags: bash, apache-http-server, php, cron, nice

I have a php script that I need to run on shared webhosting.
I have created a cron job that executes an sh script. The command in my crontab is:

`/bin/sh /home/user/script.sh`

I'm assuming it is Bourne Shell (or something compatible). The script itself is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/user/public_html/folder/
#updating DB
php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB
echo Updated DB results
```

**I have following questions**:
Can I add **nice** priorities to the php command? Or do I need to add it to the script at the cron command.

Which one is more likely to work ?

`nice 10 php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB`

Would the above command be successful at running at a lower priority?

**PS:** Basically, this script has overloaded the server before when I ran it through the browser and it affected APACHE on that server resulting in my hosts blocking the file. I have repeatedly asked them for unblock it to test it with different parameters. And now I'm trying to run it through cron at a lower priority - hoping that it won't affect APACHE. But I don't want it to create issues again, hence I'm trying to use ***nice***.

**UPDATE**: I used the batch file as shown there. I used the nice command before php inside the batch file. The only difference being:

`nice -n 10 php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB`

I added commands to run additional php scripts with the same nice property to them. All of them worked fine.

**THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE INPUT** @sm4rk0 answer solves my problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods should work, but IMO it's cleaner to put `nice` into the script just as you did in your example. After a check with `man nice` I found that example in question had wrong syntax. The right syntax would be:

```
nice -n 10 command
```

*Nicenesses range from -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable).*

And, as terdon said, 10 is the default value so "-n 10" can be omitted.

*Note: Although it will lower the process priority, nice won't make it cause less CPU load. So, if only reason to worry about is not to "choke" the `apache`, then this method is OK. But if your hosts give you some CPU time quota, this won't help a lot.*

Comment: The tech support team repeatedly blocked it after the script ran for about 10 minutes and slowed down the server. They don't seem to have CPU quota or I am well under that considering that my website itself is not resource intensive.

Comment: Is that command correct on the syntax ? I have never tried Nice nor nice with a cron in a script. And I don't want to get kicked of the server again. Pain to talk with tech

Comment: Yes. The `nice` syntax is OK. Give it a try, then come back here to update us if it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry, the syntax was not OK. Correct syntax would be: `nice -n 10 command`

Comment: Actually, just `nice command` is enough, it will run the command with a priority of 10 by default.

Comment: `nice -n 10 php -q ./run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/updateDB`  

worked just perfectly. I ran multiple php files one after another with no hickups. Checked with the tech and they said the server was fine as well.